# Using the Trial version of UFT together with the Trial version of ALM

Tags: java, hp-uft, license-key, hp-alm

I am trying to set up ALM with UFT as Demo Versions. Both programs are demo versions.

I have already installed ALM, but find had to mess with the Java-Paths to get it working with a Java Application that i want to test.

I have the problem that the bridge between UFT and ALM does not seem to work, because there seems to be a licensing issue. I cannot post a screenshot, because ALM seems to have stopped working after I disabled the java path environment variables.

Can i use a Community or Demo-license for ALM and UFT to work together?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting while trying to connect 'em?

Comment: I was getting a "license error". I reinstalled ALM on a seperate Virtual Machine and now it is working.